# Access DoCmd.OpenForm

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I developed a project for warehouse. The application user interface is on MS access and database on MS Sql Server 2008.
The problem is that when below statement is executed it generate error.

```
“DoCmd.OpenForm  stDocName, ,  , stLinkCriteria”
```

The error is that:

> Connection failed:
>   SQLState: '01000'
>   SQL Server Error: 53
>   [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen
>   (Connect()).
>   Connection failed:
>   SQLState: '08001'
>   SQL Server Error:17
>   [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not
>   exist or access denied.

Comment: The error message seem straight forward to me. What troubleshooting steps have you taken so far?

Comment: Are those quotes around your pasted code only in this post or also in your code?

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the link criteria and see if the error goes away.
2. If the form has an underlying data source, try to open that from the database window and see if the error happens.

Comment: i remove the link criteria but it also gives same error.

Comment: Eliminate things like forms, VBA, link and where clauses. It is a waste of time to run down that road. The suggestion here is to simply open the linked table. Can you from Access UI simply scroll down to the table the form is based on and open that table. So no VBA, no forms, no code, don’t bother with this huge extra set of variables. The suggestion here is to NOT play with the form and simply open the table. Can you simple open the table. If you can’t simple open a linked table then all is lost and all is a waste of time.